# How to access user's "vanityName" through the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I was directed here by LinkedIn customer support for technical assistance by LinkedIn engineers.

I'm part of a developer team building a platform to help improve the legitimacy of online petitions. We're trying to enhance user credibility by letting individuals provably link their LinkedIn profiles through the OAuth API. However with only lite_profile access, we can't establish a link to a user's profile.

The list of developer products (https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/209385445/products) doesn't include an option that fits our use case, so I'm reaching out to get help in navigating this. How can we get permission to access users' basic profile information (in particular the 'vanityName' property) through the LinkedIn API?

#linkedin

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR: to access the user's vanityName you need to use the `r_basicprofile` scope*

Hey! The link you provided is only accessible to you since it contains your app id. Next time it's best to provide a screenshot.

Getting to your question, on the `r_liteprofile` scope they clearly say it does not give you access to anything other than the user's name and photo.

What you're looking for is the scope that gives you access to the vanityName - the **public profile URL** - which in this case is `r_basicprofile` - as you can see from the screenshot below :)

[LinkedIn Developers 'r_basicprofile' scope screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FiJO.png)